# rxjs syntax Angular 6/7

Tags: angular, rxjs

I recently updated a codebase from Angular 4 to Angular 6. Part of doing this was to move all the rxjs functions inside pipeable operators.

I'm wondering if I did the syntax wrong, because a `patch` request I was making before no longer works after the syntax update.

Here is my code that worked in Angular 4:

```js
csrfToken() {
  const url = `path/to/csrf-token`;
  const options = new RequestOptions({
    withCredentials: true,
  });
  return this.http
    .get(url, options)
    .map((res: Response) => {
      return res.text();
    })
    .map((token: string) => {
      if (!token) {
        throw new Error(
          'Successfully requested a CSRF token but the response was empty.'
        );
      }
      return token;
    });
}

writeFavorites(favorites: any[]) {
  const url = `path/to/favorites`;
  // writing favorites requires CSRF Token
  return this.csrfToken().flatMap(token => {
    const opts = new RequestOptions({
      headers: new Headers({
        'MY-TOKEN': token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }),
      withCredentials: true,
    });
    return (
      this.http
        .patch(url, JSON.stringify(favorites), opts)
        // PATH currently just replies with 200 and empty body
        .map((res: Response) => {
          return null;
        })
    );
  });
}
```

Here is the code after updating to Angular 6.

```js
csrfToken(): Observable<string> {
  const url = `path/to/csrf-token`;
  const options = {
    withCredentials: true,
  };
  return this.http.get<string>(url, options).pipe(
    map((res: Response) => {
      return res.text();
    }),
    map((token: string) => {
      if (!token) {
        throw new Error('Successfully requested a CSRF token but the response was empty.');
      }
      return token;
    })
  );
}

writeFavorites(favorites: any[]) {
  const url = `path/to/favorites`;
  // writing favorites requires CSRF Token
  return this.csrfToken().pipe(
    flatMap(token => {
      const opts = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'MY-TOKEN': token,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }),
        withCredentials: true,
      };
      return (
        this.http
          .patch(url, JSON.stringify(favorites), opts)
          // PATH currently just replies with 200 and empty body
          .pipe(
            map((res: Response) => {
              // in Angular 7 the typescript compiler 
              // rejects this assignment
              // see comment below
              return null;
            })
          )
      );
    })
  );
}


// Angular 7 - TypeScript compile error: 
// Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<Response, Promise<string>>' 
// is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<string, Promise<string>>'.
// Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

My question: Why isn't the `patch` request made after this update?

If the update is correct, then I guess the problem lies elsewhere, but I wanted to make sure since I'm also new with RXJS, so perhaps my syntax is wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you subscribe to it?

Comment: @martin Yes - this code is wrapped inside a function that gets subscribed to. The error seems to occur inside the callback of the subscribe. When it catches the error is shows `SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 8 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:16711:51) at ZoneDelegate.push.`

Comment: Then show what's inside `this.csrfToken()` because otherwise the code looks correct.

Comment: @martin I updated the code with the `csrfToken` function.

Comment: Is it possible that it is due to csrfToken? You have two mapping functions, in the first you call res.text(). If I remember correctly you needed to do this in the old http service of angular 2. Since angular 4, if I remember correctly, we have the HttpClientModule and there you probably can ommit this step. Can't say if this is the cause of your problem, but it stood out to me, so it may be worth looking into.

Answer (score -2):

if you have syntax errors in Angular 6
and rxjs V6+, just install rxjs-compat

> npm i rxjs-compat